# Inserting an external function call before/after another function call in LLVM

Tags: c, insert, llvm, call

I'm new to LLVM and would like to create an LLVM pass that performs instrumentation on a c file in the following way:

Say I'm examining the c function `lst *add(list* lst, int num)` which adds an int to a linked list. I would like to insert some instructions before and after that call, so that I can record the input and output of the function into a file. The recorder is an external tool.

Before instrumentation:

```
int val = 9;
lst = add(lst, val);
```

After Instrumentation:

```
int val = 9;
TypedObject lstObj = {type_lst, lst};
record_input("add", lstObj);

lst = add(lst, val);

TypedObject lstObj = {type_lst, lst}; 
record_output("add", lstObj);
```

The record functions receive the `type` of the `TypedObject` (Something i use in the recorder tool I've built) and the `TypedObject` itself.

I have a few questions regarding this procedure:

1. How can I recognize the specific call to `add` while iterating through the module? I need to detect a CallInst, and more specifically, one that calls `add`.
2. How do I create the instrumented instructions above? I got a little confused with creating instructions.

Thanks a lot to whoever is able to help.